# Angular - How do I detect form events from inside a directive when they are initiated in component.ts file?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive, angular-forms

If I have a component with a form input and I want to detect the two statements in the OnInit block as events inside my directive, what is the correct way to do this? I have had luck with 'input' and 'ngModelChange', but none of the events I try to listen to catch the patchValue() method for model driven forms or the straight assignment for template driven forms (even though it reflects in the DOM).

Here is my Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms' 

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:
  `
  <h5>Model form input</h5>
  <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
    <input patchable-input formControlName="input" />
  </form>

  <h5>Template form input</h5>
  <input patchable-input [(ngModel)]="input" />
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  inputForm = new FormGroup({
    input: new FormControl('')
  })

  input = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputForm.patchValue({
      input: 'testing patch'
    })

    this.input = 'testing override'
  }
}
```

Here is my Directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[patchable-input]'
})
export class PatchableInputDirective  {
  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event']) ngOnChanges($event) {
        console.log($event);
    }
}
```

and a [minimal reproduction in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-input-zrdlt6) (watch the console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `AfterViewInit` instead of `OnInit`. The reason for that is at this point in the life cycle your directive has been initialized and has subscribed to the `ngModelChange` event via the `@HostListener` decorator.

See also the [Angular Life Cycle Hooks documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-input-ysopmz)

---

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms' 

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:
  `
  <h5>Model form input</h5>
  <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
    <input patchable-input formControlName="input" />
  </form>

  <h5>Template form input</h5>
  <input patchable-input [(ngModel)]="input" />
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  inputForm = new FormGroup({
    input: new FormControl('')
  })

  input = '';

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.inputForm.patchValue({
      input: 'testing patch'
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Marked as solved because your example works as expected so, thanks!

What about updating the template driven element? When I tried setting the value of `input` I got a console error with not much of a stack trace.

Comment: @user3280523 - Sorry, I am not understanding your question. Using the stackblitz in the answer I can type in the input fields and it logs in the directive, is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I've updated [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-input-m1jfuv), see line 29, and the error it produces in the console.

Comment: @user3280523 - If you move the input assignment to `ngOnInit` it fixes the error. [modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-input-zazk6g)

Comment: Thanks for the extra help, first of all. Much appreciated. I updated that stackblitz, you're right the error goes away, but that update isn't detected in the directive. Is this just a limitation of angular? Surely there's a way for this to work under one implementation that plays nicely with model and template driven forms... if not that's really frustrating